# How to group data results by month

Tags: oracle

I have a script that I wrote that will tell me what our "On Time Delivery" or "OTD" is based on the current month. Essentially it tells us instantly if we have shipped our materials before or on our promise date.

What I am trying to do now is create a new script that will tie this into our GLPERIODS table so that I can show what the "OTD" is for each month of the year at a glance. When I run this new I get the correct period (Jan-Dec) but my OTD calculation is not grouped by period. Instead they are all the same and I think it's an average of all the data in our system.

I will post the script here as well as the results. (edit: I guess I can't post the results as it won't let me post an image) Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you and BTW, I am not a programmer, just someone who works on this stuff occasionally to get the data we are after.

```
    Select "month",
  OTD
From (Select Round((1 - ("Late" / "All")), 3) As OTD
  From (Select Round(Count(V_RELEASES_COMB.ACTUAL_SHIPDATE), 2) As "Late"
    From V_RELEASES_COMB,
      GLPERIODS
    Where To_Char(V_RELEASES_COMB.ACTUAL_SHIPDATE, 'MM/YYYY') =
      To_Char(GLPERIODS.START_DATE, 'MM/YYYY') And
      V_RELEASES_COMB.ACTUAL_SHIPDATE > V_RELEASES_COMB.PROMISE_DATE And
      V_RELEASES_COMB.ITEMNO Is Not Null And V_RELEASES_COMB.CUMM_SHIPPED > 0),
    (Select Case
        When Round(Count(V_RELEASES_COMB.ACTUAL_SHIPDATE), 2) = 0 Then 1
        Else Round(Count(V_RELEASES_COMB.ACTUAL_SHIPDATE), 2) End As "All"
    From V_RELEASES_COMB,
      GLPERIODS
    Where To_Char(V_RELEASES_COMB.ACTUAL_SHIPDATE, 'MM/YYYY') =
      To_Char(GLPERIODS.START_DATE, 'MM/YYYY') And V_RELEASES_COMB.ITEMNO Is Not
      Null And V_RELEASES_COMB.CUMM_SHIPPED > 0)),
  (Select To_Char(GLPERIODS.START_DATE, 'MONTH') As "month"
  From GLPERIODS
  Where Extract(Year From GLPERIODS.START_DATE) = Extract(Year From SysDate))
```

Ok, thank you for the help! Here is the edited script with your input added:

```
    Select "month",
  OTD
From (Select trunc(g.start_date, 'Month') mth, 
    round ( 1 - ( count(
      case when v.ACTUAL_SHIPDATE > v.PROMISE_DATE And v.ITEMNO Is Not Null 
            And v.CUMM_SHIPPED > 0 then V.ACTUAL_SHIPDATE end)
    / greatest(Count(
        case when v.ITEMNO Is Not Null And v.CUMM_SHIPPED > 0 then V.ACTUAL_SHIPDATE end
      ), 1) ) , 3) OTD
  from glperiods g
    left join v_releases_comb v 
      on trunc(v.ACTUAL_SHIPDATE, 'Month') = trunc(g.start_date, 'Month')
  group by trunc(g.start_date, 'Month')),
  (Select To_Char(GLPERIODS.START_DATE, 'MONTH') As "month"
  From GLPERIODS
  Where Extract(Year From GLPERIODS.START_DATE) = Extract(Year From SysDate))
```

The results look promising but here is what is happening:

Month     OTD 
January    .956 
January    .875 
January    .359 
January    1 
January     1 
January    1 
February   .978 
February   .562 
February   .875 
February   1 
February   1

etc.
this continues for all months.

The above is in a table format but I have no idea how to post a table on this site. I wish I could just upload a pic but it won't let me.

Answer (score 0):

This query should do the job:

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/50cb5/1)

```
select to_char(mth, 'Month') "Month", OTD
  from (Select trunc(g.start_date, 'Month') mth, 
      round ( 1 - ( count(
        case when v.ACTUAL_SHIPDATE > v.PROMISE_DATE And v.ITEMNO Is Not Null 
              And v.CUMM_SHIPPED > 0 then V.ACTUAL_SHIPDATE end)
      / greatest(Count(
          case when v.ITEMNO Is Not Null And v.CUMM_SHIPPED > 0 then V.ACTUAL_SHIPDATE end
        ), 1) ) , 3) OTD
    from glperiods g
      left join v_releases_comb v 
        on trunc(v.ACTUAL_SHIPDATE, 'Month') = trunc(g.start_date, 'Month')
    Where Extract(Year From g.START_DATE) = Extract(Year From SysDate)
    group by trunc(g.start_date, 'Month'))
  order by mth
```

Without few examples it's hard to say for sure that it's OK, it would be good to verify with something.
So if something is wrong please edit your post, add some example rows and explain.

---

Edit:
I think that creating the [view](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_8004.htm) may be more comfortable for you:

```
create or replace view v_monthly_sums as 
  Select trunc(g.start_date, 'Month') mth, 
      count(case when v.ACTUAL_SHIPDATE > v.PROMISE_DATE And v.ITEMNO Is Not Null 
        And v.CUMM_SHIPPED > 0 then V.ACTUAL_SHIPDATE end) d1,
      Count(
          case when v.ITEMNO Is Not Null And v.CUMM_SHIPPED > 0 then V.ACTUAL_SHIPDATE end
        ) d2
    from glperiods g
      left join v_releases_comb v 
        on trunc(v.ACTUAL_SHIPDATE, 'Month') = trunc(g.start_date, 'Month')
    group by trunc(g.start_date, 'Month')
```

From this view you can select all values (`select * from v_monthly_sums`), to see what it contains, do any experiments,
but for your main question you can use something like:

```
select to_char(mth, 'Month') "Month",
    case 
      when d2 = 0 then null
      else round(1-d1/d2, 3)
    end otd
  from v_monthly_sums
  where extract(Year From mth) = 2015   -- you can add here: AND D2<>0 to eliminate null rows
  order by mth
```

GLPERIODS - I suspect that this table is not needed at all, not needed in our query/view for sure, 
maybe you created it only to store dates for months which interests you.
But maybe I'm wrong and it is used somewhere else. It can by replaced in our view with simple hierarchical subquery, 
but for now let's stay with current solution. Please insert one date for each month, I did not make any protections against more dates.

Why did not your query work? - you joined one number, let's say 0,567, produced by two other complicated queries with every day from table GLPERIODS. This is the reason why you got 12 months with the same, invaluable data.

Comment: In addition to the above info I added to my post, I found out that if I remove the group by code, I get a nice table with 12 months. The problem is that the OTD value is the same for all 12 months. If I leave the group by code in, I get about 60 January's, 60 February's, etc although they seem to have some different OTD values.

Comment: Do not remove GROUP BY :) Do not add again subquery for GLPERIODS :) It produces cross join, you'll have many unnecessary rows. Just run my query, I little modified it, added `WHERE` clause for only current year dates.

Comment: Oh you are a genius. That worked! Is there a way to make the OTD value be zero (0) if there is no data? Right now it shows a 1. Thank you again!!!

Comment: But does not zero mean something other in your case? I'll think about it, please check again for some time, maybe tomorrow, I'm little busy right now.

Comment: No problem, thank you again, you have been a huge help. You have gotten me pretty much where I need to be. As a side note, maybe zero isn't right. I think I would just not have those months listed at all if there is no data. For example, we have not shipped anything in May (obviously) so right now my table should just show Jan Feb Mar and Apr.

Comment: @Mark - English is not my primary language so sometimes I say something awkward. Your dividing formula may result with value 1. 
And you substract 1 minus this formula so we get 0. And this 0 is meaningful, so if we also present zero if there were no rows this may be confusing. That and only that I thought when I wrote phrase about zeros.
If you understood it in some other way then excuse me my stupidity :D Also please see updated answer.